# Ubuntu install pylucene-6.5.0 , ivy error

Tags: ivy, pylucene

Here is the error message!

```
ant
Buildfile: /home/dingyi/pylucene-7.5.0/lucene-java-7.5.0/lucene/build.xml

ivy-availability-check:
[loadresource] Do not set property disallowed.ivy.jars.list as its length is 0.

-ivy-fail-disallowed-ivy-version:

ivy-fail:

ivy-configure:
[ivy:configure] :: Apache Ivy 2.4.0 - 20141213170938 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:configure] :: loading settings :: file = /home/dingyi/pylucene-7.5.0/lucene-java-7.5.0/lucene/top-level-ivy-settings.xml

resolve-groovy:
[ivy:cachepath] :: resolving dependencies :: org.codehaus.groovy#groovy-all-caller;working
[ivy:cachepath]     confs: [default]
[ivy:cachepath]     found org.codehaus.groovy#groovy-all;2.4.15 in public

BUILD FAILED
/home/dingyi/pylucene-7.5.0/lucene-java-7.5.0/lucene/common-build.xml:2394: impossible to resolve dependencies:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/dingyi/pylucene-7.5.0/lucene-java-7.5.0/lucene/build/ivy-resolution-cache/resolved-org.codehaus.groovy-groovy-all-caller-working.xml (没有那个文件或目录)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.xml.XmlModuleDescriptorWriter.write(XmlModuleDescriptorWriter.java:70)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.xml.XmlModuleDescriptorWriter.write(XmlModuleDescriptorWriter.java:62)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.module.descriptor.DefaultModuleDescriptor.toIvyFile(DefaultModuleDescriptor.java:563)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.DefaultResolutionCacheManager.saveResolvedModuleDescriptor(DefaultResolutionCacheManager.java:176)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:245)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:176)
    at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.resolve(Ivy.java:498)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyResolve.doExecute(IvyResolve.java:315)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:271)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyPostResolveTask.prepareAndCheck(IvyPostResolveTask.java:161)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyCachePath.doExecute(IvyCachePath.java:64)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:271)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:834)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)

Total time: 3 seconds
```

I export ANT_HOME and move ivy.jar to the ${ANT_HOME}/lib directory.

Comment: Please check how to ask questions here on SO. Posting something like this will not get you any answers and will most likely make the question closed. I see `new contributor` next to your name, hence the friendly comment :)

Comment: How do you install it ? Which command do you use ? Please provide more information..